# How to politely kill windows process from cygwin

Tags: command-line, cygwin

I do have a bat(startJboss.bat) file that starts a JBoss server. When I start it it creates an output to standard cmd (windows) console. When I want to politely end this process I just hit Ctrl + C and the shutdown of the server is as expected.

I want to start the server from cygwin console. So starting is ok, just

cmd /c startJboss.bat

and the server is up. I want to be able to politely stop it from cygwin as well. When hitting the Ctrl + C in cygwin it shuts the wrapping cmd directly but the kill signal is not propagated to the underlying process. So the server is not properly shut down.

How should I propagate the Ctrl + C signal to the process that is started in the bat file?

Comment: is it an option to use the kill command to send a signal to the process?

Comment: The kill is sent only to the "cmd" command. I need to propagate it to the startJboss.bat (it starts the server java process)

Comment: you can kill any process with the kill or killall commands...

Comment: pstree should show all the process's children, from that you could write a script to kill them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your cygwin console is mintty, it sounds like you're hitting the [mintty "Input/Output interaction with alien programs"](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Tips#inputoutput-interaction-with-alien-programs) problem (aka [mintty issue #56](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/56)). In your case this is manifesting as Ctrl-C abruptly killing rather than being passed down to the program as a signal to be caught and handled.

Unfortunately [mintty isn't a full Windows console replacement](https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html#LIMITATIONS) and various behaviours expected by "native" Windows programs are not implemented. However, you might have some joy wrapping such native programs in [winpty](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) when running them within mintty...