# How to make MinTTY close gracefully on Ctrl-C?

Tags: command-line, cygwin, window, mongodb, mintty

I would like some servers, like MongDB, to run inside terminal under Windows.

I use the following command to run them:

```
start <PATHTOMONGO>\mongod.exe --dbpath <PATHTODATA>
```

Standard Windows terminal is very rough, for example, it does not allow copy/paste easily and does not allow (easily) window resize.

So I tried MinTTY from Cygwin with the following command:

```
<PATHTOMINTTY>\mintty.exe -e <PATHTOMONGO>\mongod.exe --dbpath <PATHTODATA>
```

I found it works fine except one thing: if I press Ctrl-C, it just kills server, does not allowing it to shutdown gracefully.

If I use the following command:

```
<PATHTOMINTTY>\mintty.exe --hold always -e <PATHTOMONGO>\mongod.exe --dbpath <PATHTODATA>
```

I see red message appear at the end of server output

```
<PATHTOMONGO>\mongod.exe: Interrupt
```

and server just stops.

Contrary, in Windows `start` it prints many messages indicating graceful shutdown.

Looks like `mintty` performs some translation of `Ctrl-C` key combination. How to avoid / configure this?

Comment: It works normally with Cygwin Bash for me.

Comment: Try mongodb as I described please

Answer (score 1):

You're a victim of the infamous [mintty issue #56 - Improve support for native console programs](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/56). The [mintty wiki entry "Input/Output interaction with alien programs"](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Tips#inputoutput-interaction-with-alien-programs) points out you can work around the problem by using a wrapper like [winpty](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) when running the problem program within mintty.

(This question is likely a duplicate of [How to politely kill windows process from cygwin](https://superuser.com/q/606201/675038))